# Redirect From Pretty URL to .html URL

Tags: html, .htaccess, url, redirect

I have recently switched from using Wordpress to a static html only site. When I remade each page (there are only 6 pages total) I kept the same URL name.

Example: https://reactiongaming.us/alteriwnet/ is now https://reactiongaming.us/alteriwnet.html

My issues is that old links and Google search results contain the  reactiongaming.us/alteriwnet/ version which results in a 404 error. I have tried various .htaccess methods for "pretty URLs but none worked. Usually, these questions were asked on how to redirect from a .html URL to a pretty URL, but I'm trying to do the opposite.

There are only 6 URLs I need to redirect in total from reactiongaming.us/example/ to reactiongaming.us/example.html. Is there an .htaccess or other method to achieve this?

I have tried:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \.html [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=302,L]

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [L]
```

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]
```

Comment: A very simple method would be to create 1 folder for each page, and rename each (only and single) page in this folder index.htm or whatever default name for index pages your site is using.

Comment: _“I have tried various .htaccess methods”_ - please go read [ask]. You are supposed to _show us_ what you tried.

Comment: In the simplest form, `RewriteRule (.*)/$ $1.html [R=301]` should do the trick. If you have actual folders that need to be exempt from this, then a RewriteCond with the usual `!-d` condition can be put in front of that. And the `.*` pattern could be made more specific, if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Redirect` directive to redirect your old  URLs to the new URL format

```
Redirect 301 /alteriwnet/ /alteriwnet.html
```

This will 301 redirect `/alteriwnet` to `/alteriwnet.html` .

To redirect multiple URLs with just a one liner code you can use `RedirectMatch` which uses a regex based pattern

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(alteriwnet|path2|path3)/?$ /$1.html
```

References :

- Redirect directive
  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect
- RedirectMatch directive
  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectMatch

Comment: This seems pretty straightforward. How do I implement this in .htaccess? Just simply copy your code in?

Comment: @BobSmith Yes. You can use it in your `htaccess` .

Comment: I added your first example to my .htaccess but it is not working. Any ideas?

Comment: @BobSmith Do you have any other directives in htaccess that can conflict with this one? `Redirect` directive wont work if you have a `RewriteRule` that handles  `non-existant` files as `RewriteRule` directive takes precedence over `Redirect`

Comment: Just the one line from you. "Redirect 301 /alteriwnet /alteriwnet.html"

Comment: @BobSmith Okay. Do you get any error with this `Redirect`? What URL did you try?

Comment: I tried https://reactiongaming.us/alteriwnet/ and get a 404 error.

Comment: @BobSmith I added a traling slash to the pattern in `Redirect` . Please try the updated version.

Comment: Updated but it is the same result 404.

Comment: it seems like it is not reading it, but while trying yesterday I did definitely break the site with 500 errors. Could it be browser caching? i have cloudflare in development mode and tried a second browser with the same results.

Comment: I'm going to contact my host and see if its dissbled. I put "deny from all" and site still works so it is not reading it.

Comment: @BobSmith Yes ask your hosting provider to unable it for you then you will be able to use these directives.

Comment: That was the problem. I used your second suggestion and it works perfectly. Thanks.